# Unfurl link outside bot conversation

Tags: botframework

When i post a link outside the bot conversation, like in a conversation with a coworker, i've an error saying "The bot is not part of a conversation roster"

It's working inside the bot conversation !

I've following this step-by-step [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-botbuilder-linkunfurling?tabs=vs&tutorial-step=4), except the step "Update the Azure AD app registration"! My problem can't be related to this?

Bot builder JS version is "4.15.0"

The full stack trace

```
Trace: RestError: The bot is not part of the conversation roster.
    at new RestError (/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:1403:28)
    at /node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:2528:37
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  code: 'BotNotInConversationRoster',
  statusCode: 403,
  request: WebResource {
    streamResponseBody: false,
    url: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/fr/v3/conversations/19%3A6d034d50-90a1-4551-8029-23d63f85c195_ebe09ddb-51a0-4d40-9e7e-5839782cd8c9%40unq.gbl.spaces/members',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
    body: undefined,
    query: undefined,
    formData: undefined,
    withCredentials: false,
    abortSignal: undefined,
    timeout: 0,
    onUploadProgress: undefined,
    onDownloadProgress: undefined,
    proxySettings: undefined,
    keepAlive: undefined,
    agentSettings: undefined,
    operationSpec: {
      httpMethod: 'GET',
      path: 'v3/conversations/{conversationId}/members',
      urlParameters: [Array],
      responses: [Object],
      serializer: [Serializer]
    }
  },
  response: {
    body: '{"error":{"code":"BotNotInConversationRoster","message":"The bot is not part of the conversation roster."}}',
    headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
    status: 403
  },
  body: {
    error: {
      code: 'BotNotInConversationRoster',
      message: 'The bot is not part of the conversation roster.'
    }
  }
}
    at BotFrameworkAdapter.onTurnErrorHandler [as turnError] (/lib/index.js:58:13)
    at BotFrameworkAdapter.<anonymous> (/node_modules/botbuilder-core/lib/botAdapter.js:150:32)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/node_modules/botbuilder-core/lib/botAdapter.js:6:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

I'm stuck with it, because I don't known if the unfurl link are expected to work outside conversation with the bot.

-- Edit --

This error was not related to the unfurl link, i was retrieving some information in the context only available during a conversation roaster.

Comment: Seems you're getting a 403 Forbidden error. Perhaps there's a permissions issue at play? Link unfurling is supposed to work outside a direct conversation with the bot.

Comment: Edit my original post